# View not animating with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, autolayout

I've been searching around SO and have found some related posts, but none that have (yet) solved my problem.

I have a view setup in my storyboard, with a constraint hooked up through an IBOulet.  Upon a certain action, the view should move up (or down to it's initial position).  For the life of me, I cannot get it to work properly.  Prior to autolayout, I ran this bit of code:

```
- (void)animateStarBackground:(NSString *)animationID
                 finished:(NSNumber *)finished
                  context:(void *)context
                   myView:(UIView *)myView
                     xPos:(float)xPos
                     yPos:(float)yPos {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    myView.center = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

It used to work great, but anyway... we all know that this doesn't work in Autolayout anymore.  So I changed it to the following:

```
-(void)animateButton:(UIView *)myView {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0f animations:^{
        _viewConstA.constant = 45.0;
        [myView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

}

When the action occurs, instead of starting in it's initial position as set in the Storyboard,  it starts off as a 1x1 pixel view in the top left hand corner and animates *downward* into it's final resting place (instead of moving up 15 pixels as I had intended it to).

Now, if I take out the **[myView layoutIfNeeded];** portion, the action positions the view in exactly the right place... BUT it doesn't animate there.  It's just instantly there as the view appears.

The first screen grab is the initial location.
2nd grab is what's supposed to be the views final resting place.
3rd is the view animating from the wrong spot and direction.

Thoughts / comments?  What the heck am I doing wrong?  I thought this would be so easy...  I've got to be missing something obvious.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see that when I do it in `viewDidLoad` but works properly when I defer to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Wait.  so you're saying when you put [self animateButton:myView]; in your viewDidAppear, it's NOT animating in from the 1x1 pixel in the top left?  Huh... it's happening for me no matter which spot I load it in.  I'm inclined to just make two different storyboards -- one for iPhone 5 and one for everything else, and just continue to use my original code.  Ugh, this is frustrating.

Comment: Yes, that's my experience. I just tested it to make sure I wasn't losing my mind and confirmed it. Bottom line, doing block-based animation of constraints (including the call to `layoutIfNeeded`) in `viewDidAppear` (or later) works fine for me, though when I do it in `viewDidLoad` I see the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I call the following block-based animation from `viewDidLoad`, it animates the frame from `CGRectZero` to the final location. But if I call this from `viewDidAppear`, it works just as expected.

```
- (void)animateMovementByConstraint
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.topLayoutConstraint.constant = 100;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}
```

(In this example, `topLayoutConstraint` is an `IBOutlet` that I defined in Interface Builder for the top vertical constraint on the control that I wanted to animate.)

With auto layout, since I've started initiating my animations in `viewDidAppear`, I haven't had any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they definitely helped in the diagnosis.  Overall, I had two problems.  1.) I moved [self animateButton]; into viewDidAppear INSTEAD of viewWillAppear.  2.) I took a hint from your code again and changed [myView layoutIfNeeded]; over to [self.view layoutIfNeeded];  Bam -- works great!  Thanks for you help.